# how to integrate google map using react-native-navigation

Tags: react-native

I want to show the current location with animation arrow and also place some dummy images(SVG images) on the map.

Please any one help for me.

Answer (score 0):

There is a great library called [react-native-maps](https://github.com/react-community/react-native-maps) where you can use google maps for both iOS and Android or use google maps for android and native apple maps for iOS.

Also this supports various animations and custom markers. You can use below link to find out uses of this library.

[Link](https://github.com/react-community/react-native-maps#general-usage)

Comment: how can I place multiple icons?

Comment: if you mean list of markers on the map, sure you can do that.

Comment: yes I used react native maps only, but how can I find the latitude and longitude for around 20 kms from the current location and points that locations with multiple markers. can you suggest?

Comment: geoLocation.getCurrentPosition() method I used for current location but for near 20 kms surroundings which google API I can use?