# ReactNative: how to show multiple markers with custom image around 20kms

Tags: react-native

I want to show multiple markers around 20 km distance from the current location using google api.

also use custom images for the markers.

please any one suggest me the best solution here

Comment: I think this is related : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53133437/how-to-integrate-google-map-using-react-native-navigation

Comment: can you suggest the google api for fetching surrounding locations lat and long